# Should I put grout or something else between hardwood floor and slate stone gap?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, grout, stone

This is a new hardwood floor that is next to my slate stone flooring:

[image]

The cut was nice and there is about an inch gap in between:

[image]

My hardwood floor guy recommended to just leave it like that and not fill with grout.

Is it a good idea to leave it alone like that? And if so, would it get dusty and even broken at the edge over time?

If I fill with grout, would it look ugly? Maybe due to color mismatch with the old grout?

Any other idea or suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Typically you'd make a cut like that with some particular transition plan in mind. Random cuts at random widths don't leave you with a lot of great options. at this point I think your best bet is a custom curved T molding, as thin as possible and supported across the gap.

Comment: And your hardwood floor guy is not very good at what he does. That's a truly unprofessional suggestion.

Comment: You learn something new every day, and here's what I just learned. Flexible T moldings exist that can be stained like wood. [For example](https://youtu.be/ezeEAR1MUlc).

Answer (score 2):

That is not acceptable finished work and the hardwood floor installer should deal with it. There are many options for finishing that kind of transition and leaving a 1” gap with the subfloor exposed is NOT one of them.